¿Cómo configurar cómodamente librerías externas en visual studio code con C++?
Recientemente empecé a usar Visual Studio Code, y pensaba que por ser el "hermano pequeño" del Visual Studio, iba a ser más eficiente y más cómodo programar en él que en otros IDEs que usaba como CodeBlocks, específicamente para C++. Descargué la extensión y tengo el compilador de MinGW64 de MSYS, y lo configuré de acuerdo a la guía oficial hasta poder compilar y correr un Hola mundo básico. Sin embargo, la programación en C++ requiere constamente de usar librerías de terceros que a veces no se instalan en la ruta del compilador. Así que cuando quise incluir Allegro (librería que uso a menudo en varios proyectos) me encontré que, configuraciones de IntelliSense aparte, la única forma que tengo de indicarle al compilador las rutas de los #includes y librerías de Allegro es especificandolas con -I y -L en el array "args" de tasks.json, ¡y además entrecomillando y separando por comas cada elemento!, por no decir que si el proyecto tenía más de un archivo .cpp, debía indicarlos todos son un comando especial. Esto es sumamente engorroso, en comparación por ejemplo, con CodeBlocks, que cuando se trataba de proyectos entendía por sí solo que debía compilar cada uno de los archivos, y además permitía indicar las parámetros del compilador y los directorios de búsqueda en secciones separadas y armaba por sí mismo la linea de comando que pasaba al compilador, haciendo así mucho más fácil de establecer el entorno de construcción del programa; y encima de eso permitía hacer plantillas de proyectos, cosa que es muy diferente en el VSCode, ya que modificar el settings.json de la extensión de C++ hace que tenga que utilizar la misma plantilla para todos los proyectos, independientemente de las librerías que use. Entonces mi pregunta es si existe una manera de hacer todo esto más sencillo y cómodo en VSCode, o cómo crear plantillas de proyectos en este IDE, o si simplemente debería abandonar VSCcode para C++ y hacer todos mis proyectos en este lenguaje con CodeBlocks

La verdad que Visual Studio Code no me gusta para C++, pero puedes configurar algunas cosas, tanto para compilar como para el intellisense. Para el último te interesa modificar las carpetas de inclusión. Una forma cómoda que encontré es mediante un proyecto de Cmake. La extensión de Cmake se encarga de configurar bien las sugerencias.

VSCode no es un IDE, es meramente un editor con plugins que le añaden capacidades "extra". Pero nunca va a ser tan "plug and play" como un IDE específico para un determinado lenguaje :)
